# Sprite has no attribute image

Tags: python, pygame

So I have a player class setup with pygame. Everytime I run my code however it gives me a "type object 'playnode' has no attribute 'image'" error. Any help would be great.

Player Class:

```
import pygame,random

class playnode(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load("amogus png.png")
        self.image = pygame.transform.smoothscale(self.image, (15,15))

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = pos
        self.speed = pygame.math.Vector2(0, 5)
        self.speed.rotate_ip(random.randint(0, 360))


        self.time = 0
    def update(self,x_speed,y_speed):
        self.rect.move_ip(x_speed, y_speed)
```

Main:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
on = True
from Level import *

size = (width, height) = 850, 480
import Player

players = pygame.sprite.Group()
color = (54, 96, 230)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size, RESIZABLE)
p_v_x = 0
p_v_y = 0

posTuple = tuple((p_v_x, p_v_y))

enemyNum = 10


def innit():
    players = pygame.sprite.Group
    Enemies = pygame.sprite.Group

    players.add(playnode)


def event_processor():
    global on, success
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            on = False


def main():
    global on
    innit()
    while on == True:
        clock.tick(60)
        event_processor()

        # screen.fill(color)
        screen.blit(Player.playnode.image, Player.playnode.rect)
        pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Random crap so I can post this ajsodijaoikdjaoijdoisajoidjioajdoisajoidjaosijdiosjasidojoiasdjiodjpiodfjiopjsjfoij;aokjkofjdiaojfopiajiopafjiopajdoipfjdoiojpsjfpoiajfdopijaopidfjopidsajfiopj9uipwhfgioujnwiouonbhgoiunowjnvoiejqwownoivnwe

Comment: It would be helpful if you edit your question to include a [mcve], as your code seems incomplete. Including the full exception traceback will make it easier to track down your issue. The line `screen.blit(Player..` is incorrect, you should reference the class instance. However, as you've sensibly used [sprite groups](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw), you can replace that line with `players.draw(screen)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the class variables of the player instead of the instance variables, so you first need to create a instance of the player before referencing it

example:

```py
player = Player(...)
...
screen.blit(player .playnode.image, player .playnode.rect)
```